# Different number of nodes under a surface Abaqus?

Tags: python, mesh, abaqus

Abaqus 6.14-1, Win 7, x64.

I create a thin box 80 x 120 x 0.5 then seed the edges with a 0.5 spacing.

I then create 2 models one with hex elements & a second with tets.
[image: hex model]
[image: close up of tet model]

I then create a surface (Surf-2, dont ask) on the top most xy surface of the box.

Now I run the following script to obtain the node labels & coordinates of nodes under Surf-2...

```
mySurf = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.surfaces['Surf-2']

surfNodes = []
surfNodesLabels = []
nodeInfo = open('LoadSurfaceNodes.txt','w')
for eNode in mySurf.nodes:
    surfNodes.append(eNode.coordinates)
    surfNodesLabels.append(eNode.label)
    outStr = str(eNode.label) + ',' + str(eNode.coordinates[0]) + ',' + str(eNode.coordinates[1]) + ',' + str(eNode.coordinates[2]) + '\n'
    print outStr
    nodeInfo.write(outStr)
nodeInfo.close()

print len(surfNodesLabels)
```

For the hex model I get 9801 (81 x 121) as expected.

For the tet model I get 38801 errr not as expected!

As far as I can see regardless of type of element there are not actually a different number of nodes under Surf-2 in each case.

So why the discrepancy?

EDIT & SOLUTION!

The tetrahedral elements were quadratic, as soon as they were swapped for linear everything agreed with everything else.